# Can I use T-SQL to launch notepad or other UI app?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Nothing important or fancy, I am creating a demo jpeg in SQL Server and don't want to take the extra step of having to launch mspaint directly after running my script in order to see it.  It would be nice if the script could just do the launching for me.

I have seen a number of posts on this subject and it looks like xp_cmdshell won't work for a UI-based app.  Does anybody know of any way within a simple T-SQL script to launch notepad or mspaint or any other UI-based app without having to resort to SSIS or ServiceBroker?  TIA

Comment: TSQL is not meant for opening notepad... Why not this handled in middle of front tier?

Comment: It's just a simple demo.  I was kind of hoping to avoid turning it into a major project.

Comment: Why not use powershell to run your script, then launch mspaint? You can use `sqlcmd` or `bcp` from a powershell script, then run mspaint from the powershell script?

Comment: "creating a demo jpeg in SQL Server" - can you elaborate on how that works.

Comment: (Smiley) I am demo-ing SQL Server R services for my users group and outputting a plot of a machine learning algorithm.  I think the sqlcmd/powershell will probably be best.  I was hoping I could be a little lazy considering all the time I put making the rest of it work - alas.

Comment: A demo of what exactly? I ask because `xp_cmdshell` is usually disabled or made inaccessible due to the inherent security issues it poses.

Comment: see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046(SQL.90).aspx you could start an application such as notepad or mspaint, but that's about as much as you can do. powershell offers more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am demo-ing SQL Server R services for my users group and outputting a plot of a machine learning algorithm

If I understand you correctly you want to show result from SQL Server R Services (during demo). I would recommend to install **[SSMS Boost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/)** for SSMS and use SSMS ResultGrid Visualizers:

[image]

<sup>Image from: http://www.ssmsboost.com/Content/images/Feature/ssms-add-in-results-grid-visualizers.png</sup>

Sample:

- present TSQL/R script
- execute it
- visualize varbinary data(jpeg)